# Non-symmetric random walk with stop value.

Tags: probability

A random walk with a probability $0.7$ being $+1$ and $0.3$ being $-1$. You start from $0$ and take $100$ steps.

However, there is a stop loss at $-10$, once the random walk hit $-10$ it stops there and use -10 as the final value. What is the expected value that you stop on?

Comment: And... your take on this would be?

Comment: I have no idea where to start.

Comment: And you never solved any similar and/or simpler problem related to this one?

Comment: So without the $-10$ lower limit, the expected value would be $40$. I'd assume you'd take the probability of it ending up below $-10$ and assign a value of $-10$ to it and let all the numbers above $-10$ to take on their normal values but I don't know how to get those probabilities.